# Getting client_customer_id after Oauth

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I am attempting to pull in a users account hierarchy after I've received their three credentials through Oauth access ('client_id','client_secret','refresh_token'). Google API code sample I am referring to: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/account-management#get-the-account-hierarchy-under-the-current-account

When I attempted to do this with my own account I had signed up with, `client_customer_id` was not needed in the .yml file, and I was successfully able to pull in the account hierarcy. When an account that was not associated with my original email gave oauth access I received an `googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [AuthorizationError.NO_CUSTOMER_FOUND @ ]`.

This error went away when I included their `client_customer_id` manually into the yml file. I feel as though I'm in a Catch-22, I need a `client_customer_id` to access the `client_customer_id`??

So, my question is, how can I pull in the `client_customer_id` that will give me access to the account hierarchy?